# EM Dash in CSV causing issues with Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, unicode, utf-8

I  have encountered an issue with EM Dash in my csv raw data file that prevents Pandas from reading the CSV.

I ran a few variations below

```
    datalocation = filepath
    df = pd.read_csv(datalocation)
```

Received the error: 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)'

other variation includes

```
    df = pd.read_csv(datalocation, encoding='utf-8')
    df = pd.read_csv(datalocation, encoding='utf-16')
```

Received the error:'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte'

```
    df = pd.read_csv(datalocation, na_values=['—'])
```

Received the error:'line contains NULL byte'

If it was successful, the dataframe should be similar to the sample table below.

```
+---------+------+----------+--------+
| Country | Date | Delivery | Region |
+---------+------+----------+--------+
| a       | —    | 10       | foo    |
| b       | —    | 30       | —      |
| c       | 2    | —50      | foo—   |
| —       | —    | 20       | —bar   |
| a       | —    | 40       | bar—   |
| —       | —    | —6—      | bar    |
| b       | —    | 90—      | foo    |
| c       | —    | 70       | bar    |
| a       | —    | 80       | foo    |
| c       | —    | 100      | foo—   |
+---------+------+----------+--------+
```

After spending time researching the resources on SO, I understand that it has to do with some conflict across Unicode/UTF-8/ASCII.

Is there a way to remove all the EM Dash's prior to running 'pd.read_csv'? Keep in mind, I don't know the precise cells of all the EM Dash's in the csv raw file.

Comment: What happens if you try `encoding='iso-8859-1'` ?

Comment: @DanielMartin

Just tried entering that in and received this error:

_UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)_

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured out how to do this by pre-processing the data set into a new file before reading it! Wanted to share the methodology with anyone that is also running into this problem.

```
import os, re
import pandas as pd

EMDASH = '—'

with open('scrubbed_file','wt') as outfile:
    with open('original_file_location','rt') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(re.sub(EMDASH,'-',line))

df = pd.read_csv('scrubbed_file', engine='python',
                     encoding='utf_16_le',
                     names=['Country', 'Date', 'Delivery', 'Region'], 
                     delimiter='\t',
                     quotechar='"',
                     skiprows=2, skip_footer=2, thousands = ',')
```

Hope this helps with anyone running into trouble with some problematic characters in their data frame.